# How to install ssl in Tomcat 7 - Amazon ec2 ubuntu instance

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu, ssl, amazon-ec2

I have created self signed certificate(SSL) and hosted Spring MVC web application at Intranet Ubuntu Server - Tomcat 7 and it's working fine.

But when i deploy this application to Amazon EC2 - Ubuntu with Tomcat 7, port 8443 doesn't respond.

In security group, PORT 80,8080,8443 and 22 are open.

Please suggest me some ways to solve this issue.

Thanks

@Edit: Catalina.log  (Status of my server after installing ssl)

```
Jun 11, 2015 1:01:08 AM org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm authenticate
WARNING: An attempt was made to authenticate the locked user "tomcat"
..

    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    Jun 11, 2015 5:19:38 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"]
    Jun 11, 2015 5:19:38 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
    Jun 11, 2015 5:19:38 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start

INFO: Server startup in 1385 ms
```

Comment: Have you configured SSL on port 8443 in the Tomcat server.xml file on the EC2 instance? Do you see any error messages in the Tomcat logs on startup?

Answer (score 0):

Login to the AWS console and goto the Security Groups section Here, in the Inbound add a new rule named Custom TCP Rule and enter the custom port range 8443.  May be this helps.